# Clear build queue in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I've got a large number of queued builds in TFS 2015 (14.95.25122.0) which I don't wish to run. Is there a way to remove them all with a single command (and preferably from the TFS web interface) or will I have to open each build and cancel them one by one?

Answer (score 3):

You can multi-select the rows in the Web Access and Right Click and Cancel:
[image: Queued builds]

Comment: hold down shift when selecting the items and when clicking cancel. the popup will then change to cancel these builds instead of a specific one